# Убрать дублирование кода при проверке прав

Tags: python, django

У меня есть некоторый объект, для которого определяются различные права, примерно так:

```
class Post(Model):
    ...

    @staticmethod
    def can_be_seen(user):
        return Q(author=user) | Q(published=True)
```

Так я могу получить все посты, которые доступны пользователю:

```
posts = Post.objects.filter(Post.can_be_seen(reuest.user))
```

Однако если у меня есть пост и я хочу проверить, может ли его видеть конкретный пользователь, приходится продублировать метод `can_be_seen`:

```
class Post(Model):
    ...

    @staticmethod
    def can_be_seen_q(user):
        return Q(author=user) | Q(published=True)

    def can_be_seen(self, user):
        return self.author == user or self.published
```

Вопрос: как избавиться от дублирования кода? В идеале, хочется компилировать объекты `Q` в функции, которые принимают инстанс модели и возвращают `True`/`False`, примерно так:

```
class Post(Model):
    ...

    can_be_seen = compile_query(
        Q(author=Placeholder('user')) | Q(published=True)
    )


Post.can_be_seen.q(user=request.user)  # возвращает объект Q
post.can_be_seen(user=request.user)  # возвращает True/False
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно парсить запрос:

```
from django.db.models import Q
from operator import __and__, __or__


def parse(q, equal):
    if isinstance(q, tuple):
        return equal(*q)
    connector = __and__ if q.connector == Q.AND else __or__
    value = q.children[0]
    value = parse(value, equal)
    for i in q.children[1:]:
        i = parse(i, equal)
        value = connector(value, i)
    return value


q = Q(tt='tt') & (Q(author='author') | Q(published=True))
print parse(q, lambda a,b: a == b)
```

Пример с объектом:

```
class Post:

    def __init__(self, author, published):
        self.author = author
        self.published = published


obj = Post(author='iam', published=True)

def by_obj(q, obj):
    return parse(q, lambda a,b: getattr(obj, a) == b)

def can_be_seen(user):
    return Q(author=user) & Q(published=True)

print by_obj(can_be_seen('iam'), obj)
```

Если нужно учитывать суффиксы типа `__isnull`, `__gt` и прочее, то придется значительно расширить функцию `equal`.